# Vertical Carousel with multiple item in large screen, but single image with default bootstrap in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to make some image preview to display product image, but it should be different based on the screen size (responsive).

The desktop view should be like below image

[image: Desktop view]

But the mobile view should be like the default bootstrap view like below

[image: mobile view]

I've tried like this [Example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/k2dz3)

But for the mobile view, I've no Idea.. please help me

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin called [tinyslider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider) its match with your requirement.
Try that one.